# can we make Angular 6 routing as http:// localhost/index.html#/dashboard like this

Tags: angular

I developed angular applications where in url the routing includes `index.html#/dashboard` 
the views will change like `#/reports` `#/tracking` but `index.html` stay in url.

I need to resemble same functionality in angular framework with like `index.html` as stick in url and views has to change.I have a constraint like this url format `index.html` as to stay in url

can any one have already did like this pls help on this

Comment: [Hash Location Strategy](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/)

Answer (score 1):

**HashLocationStartegy is used in angular for specifying # in routes**

To enable HashLocationStrategy in an Angular application we pass `{useHash: true}` when we are providing our routes with RouterModule, like so:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

URL can contain some data prepended with a # character.

**The # part of the url is called the hash fragment.**

It’s normally used so that people can link to a particular section in an HTML page, specifically anchor tags.
for example, if there is an anchor tag with a name attribute of routing-strategies like so:

```
<a name="routing-strategies"></a>
```

Then if you created a bookmark of

```
http://somedomain.com/page#routing-strategies
```

Then the browser would open somedomain.com/page and then scroll down so that the `<a name="routing-strategies"></a>` tag is at the top of the page.

The important characteristic is that anything past the # in a URL never gets sent to the server.

So if your URL was `https://codecraft.tv/contact/#/abc/xy/dg` then the browser makes a GET request to https://codecraft.tv/contact/ only.

The #/abc/xy/dg part of the URL is never sent.

Another way to think about the hash fragment, since it’s never sent to the server, is that it's for storing the state of your client application.

It’s, therefore, an ideal solution for implementing client-side routing:-

It’s part of the URL so can be bookmarked and sent to other people.

It won’t confuse the server side since the hash fragment is never sent to the server.

It can be programmatically changed via JavaScript.

And that’s exactly why, for a number of years, the primary way of implementing client-side routing was via hash fragments.

Taking a look at the app we’ve built so far if running locally the URLs look something like:

```
localhost:4040/#/search
localhost:4040/#/artist/1234/tracks
```

According to the server, there is only ever one URL localhost:4040, the other hash fragment stuff is ignored by the server.

Below is detailed information
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/